# SpaCy: How to manually set POS tag for vertical bar "|"?

Tags: spacy, pos-tagger

When text is tagged by SpaCy, the vertical bar "|" is assigned different POS tags depending on the context, such as "ADV" , "DEL"... While I want "|" to be recognized as "PUNC". Is there a way to force this POS for "|" ?

I tried this command and it didn't work.

```
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case('|', [{ORTH: '|', POS: PUNC}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a simple pipe into the pipeline, right after the `tagger` :

```
def pos_postprocessor_pipe(doc) :
    for token in doc :
        if token.text == '|':
            token.pos_ = 'PUNCT'
    return doc

 nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
 nlp.add_pipe(pos_postprocessor_pipe, name="pos_postprocessor", after='tagger')
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51766157/how-to-force-a-pos-tag-in-spacy-before-after-tagger/51776803?noredirect=1#comment114503210_51776803) to overwrite the tags, but that seems to be for an old version of spaCy; it doesn't work in 2.3.1.

You can set values on tokens, so you can do something like this:

```
import spacy
from spacy.symbols import NOUN
nlp = spacy.load('en')

words = nlp("...")
for word in words:
    if word.text == "|":
        word.pos = NOUN
```

However, it's likely that it's easier to just add an exception for the pipe wherever it's causing you issues.

---

Adding an exception for the pipe would look like this.

```
for word in nlp(...):
    pos = word.pos_
    if word.text == "|":
        pos = "PUNCT"
    
    do_stuff(word, pos)
```

Comment: can you please add an example for "adding an exception to the pipe" ?