# How to force a certain tag in spaCy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm using spaCy `'3.0.0rc2'` with a custom model. Unfortunately my training data is low in hyphens (-), therefore the hyphen often gets tagged as `NOUN`.

Is there some way to force a certain `tag` ***or*** `pos`, to make sure that ***all*** the  `-` tokens get tagged with `PUNCT`?

Basically I am looking for a solution like proposed in the answer to this question here:
[How to force a pos tag in spacy before/after tagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51766157/how-to-force-a-pos-tag-in-spacy-before-after-tagger/51776803)

Unfortunately this does not seem to work *anymore* (at least for spaCy 3) and raises an error:

```
ValueError: [E1005] Unable to set attribute 'POS' in tokenizer exception for '{G}'. Tokenizer exceptions are only allowed to specify ORTH and NORM.
```

*(Same when trying to assign the `TAG` attribute)*

I know that it would be possible to create a custom component with a `Matcher` that looks just for the hyphen and assigns the right tag. However this seems to be overkill when considering that I currently just want to handle one token.

Is there some way to force tags in spaCy 3, *without re-tagging during processing using a custom component*?

Ideally I would want to modify the `TAG` attribute and let the `POS` attribute get assigned automatically by spaCy based on that `TAG` attribute.
As in the [spacy-annotations](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#pos-en) `TAG=HYPH` should be mapped to `POS=PUNCT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spaCy v3, exceptions like this can be implemented in the `attribute_ruler` component:

```py
ruler = nlp.add_pipe("attribute_ruler")
patterns = [[{"ORTH": "-"}]]
attrs = {"TAG": "HYPH", "POS": "PUNCT"}
ruler.add(patterns=patterns, attrs=attrs)
```

Be aware that the attribute ruler runs the pattern matching once based on the initial `Doc` state, so you can't use the output attrs of one rule as the input pattern for another. This comes up in pipelines like `en_core_web_sm`, where the included attribute ruler does the tag->pos mapping. So if you have another rule that should match on a pos pattern, you'd have to add a second attribute ruler component to handle those cases.

See: https://nightly.spacy.io/api/attributeruler

Comment: Pretty much what I was looking for, thanks a lot!
This is not exactly related, but maybe you can help me out :) I wonder why the tags get overwritten when I place the ruler before the `morphologizer`.
Isn't it possible for the `morphologizer` to use the these "tagger" features to predict the other other morphological features?

Comment: It's technically possible for a component to do this, but no, the morphologizer doesn't look at any tag values. What's not consistent / configurable across all the various components is whether they overwrite existing annotation. The morphologizer currently overwrites everything, but the tagger doesn't, and it's not configurable at this point.

Comment: Then I know at least this is not possible, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The correct method is to first get the existing instance of the attribute_ruler by:
`ruler = nlp.get_pipe("attribute_ruler")`.

The below is a complete example from the official [guide](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#sbd):

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
text = "I saw The Who perform. Who did you see?"
doc1 = nlp(text)
print(doc1[2].tag_, doc1[2].pos_)  # DT DET
print(doc1[3].tag_, doc1[3].pos_)  # WP PRON

# Add attribute ruler with exception for "The Who" as NNP/PROPN NNP/PROPN
ruler = nlp.get_pipe("attribute_ruler")
# Pattern to match "The Who"
patterns = [[{"LOWER": "the"}, {"TEXT": "Who"}]]
# The attributes to assign to the matched token
attrs = {"TAG": "NNP", "POS": "PROPN"}
# Add rules to the attribute ruler
ruler.add(patterns=patterns, attrs=attrs, index=0)  # "The" in "The Who"
ruler.add(patterns=patterns, attrs=attrs, index=1)  # "Who" in "The Who"

doc2 = nlp(text)
print(doc2[2].tag_, doc2[2].pos_)  # NNP PROPN
print(doc2[3].tag_, doc2[3].pos_)  # NNP PROPN
# The second "Who" remains unmodified
print(doc2[5].tag_, doc2[5].pos_)  # WP PRON
```