# How do I make it more likely that spacy mark a NOUN as VERB?

Tags: spacy

This is my code

spacy==3.6.1

```
import spacy

try:
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
    print(
        print(
            "SpaCy model not found. Please run `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`"
        )
    )

doc = nlp("Buy groceries.")
for sent in doc.sents:
    print(f"Sentence: {sent.text}")
    for token in sent:
        print(f"{token.text}: {token.pos_}")
```

it marks `Buy` as NOUN.

I understand this is called an ambiguity. How do I make it such that any ambiguous VERB/NOUN is overweighted towards VERB?

Esp if it's followed by another NOUN and preceding it is a PUNC or is at start of sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I had come across such ambiguity using small spacy models, and I would suggest you use large model 'en_core_web_lg', as they are more robust and would POS tag "Buy" as a verb. However, if you still want to use 'en_core_web_sm', and your text contain instructions structure (e.g., buy this, do this, etc.) I would suggest you to change the input sentence to lower case.

```
doc = nlp("Buy groceries.".lower())
```

Caveat: This lower case hack might not work in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

The small model has problems with imperatives. See for example the following [issue comment](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/144#issuecomment-149588906) from 2015:

> So, one awkwardness is that currently spaCy's parser is pretty crap on imperatives (e.g. "Go to the zoo"), because it has almost none of these in its training data.

Apart from using a bigger model you can define some exceptions.

If you know in advance which words you want to retag, and they should be retagged always, then you can use the approach in [How to force a certain tag in spaCy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65699672/how-to-force-a-certain-tag-in-spacy). Note that `add_pipe("attribute_ruler")` needs to be replaced by `get_pipe("attribute_ruler")`.

```py
# tag 'Buy' always as VERB
ruler = nlp.get_pipe("attribute_ruler")
patterns = [[{"ORTH": "Buy"}]]
attrs = {"TAG": "BUY", "POS": "VERB"}
ruler.add(patterns=patterns, attrs=attrs)
```

If you want to do conditional retagging then you can apply some postprocessing. This also allows to use patterns so you don't need to know the offending words in advance. Implementing your pattern of [start of sentence or punct], [noun], [noun], adapted from [SpaCy: How to manually set POS tag for vertical bar "|"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64731868/spacy-how-to-manually-set-pos-tag-for-vertical-bar):

```py
import spacy

def prefer_verb(doc):
    for sent in doc.sents:
        print(f"Sentence: {sent.text}")
        for token in sent:
            if token.pos_ == "NOUN":
                if(len(sent) > token.i + 1 and (token.i == 0 or doc[token.i-1].pos_ == "PUNCT") and doc[token.i+1].pos_ == "NOUN"):
                    token.pos_ = "VERB"
            print(f"{token.i}. {token.text}: {token.tag_} {token.pos_}")
    return doc

try:
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
    print(
        print(
            "SpaCy model not found. Please run `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`"
        )
    )

doc = nlp("Buy groceries.")

doc = prefer_verb(doc)
```

Result:

```
Sentence: Buy groceries.
0. Buy: NN VERB
1. groceries: NNS NOUN
2. .: . PUNCT
```

Note that `pos_` is adjusted but `tag_` is not, leading to output of `NN VERB`. This is of course easy to fix (by also setting `tag_`) but you can also leave it to have some 'trace' of the postprocessing.

Alternatively you can try to see if the word in a different context *would* be classified as a verb, and change it only in that case. In the example below I picked the context *I will X.*

```py
def prefer_verb(doc):
    for sent in doc.sents:
        print(f"Sentence: {sent.text}")
        for token in sent:
            if token.pos_ == "NOUN":
                # re-parse in different context
                doc2 = nlp(f"I will {token.text}.")
                if doc2[2].pos_ == "VERB":
                    token.pos_ = "VERB"
            print(f"{token.i}. {token.text}: {token.tag_} {token.pos_}")
    return doc
```

Note that this is a bit risky as it might assign VERB to words that are never a verb, just because of the altered sentence structure. In this particular example it works fine though.